# Showing a class of subharmonic functions are bounded by 0

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is the punctured disk $0< |z| < 1$ and if $f$ is given by $f(\zeta)=0$ for $|\zeta|=1$, $f(0)=1$, show that all functions $v\in B(f)$ are $\le 0$ in $\Omega$.

$B(f)$ is the class of functions $v$ such that

(a) $v$ is subharmonic

(b) $\overline{\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow \zeta}}\, v(z)\le f(\zeta)$ for all $\zeta$ in the boundary of $\Omega$

I know how to show that all the functions $v$ are $\le 1$ in $\Omega$, but I am unsure how to show they are less than or equal to 0. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v\in B(f)$ and $\epsilon>0$ define $$v_\epsilon(z)=v(z)+\epsilon\log|z|.$$Then $v\in B(f)$ implies $v_\epsilon\in B(0)$, so $v_\epsilon\le0$. Let $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: You’re correct, I meant less than or equal to. Do you truly mean $f\in B(f)$? Since $f$ is not defined on $\Omega$ I don’t understand this statement.

Comment: That was a typo for $v\in B(f)$, sorry.